# rendering an array of objects with a forEach() method

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues rendering an array of objects that are produced by a class using a forEach method.

I've updated the question so that other individuals can have a live example of the problem. this code includes the html, and JavaScript sections where i'm having the issues.

```js
class Project {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tasksArr = [];
    }
    get nameOfProject() {
        return this.name;
    }
    addTasksToProject(name, dueDate) {
        let newTask = new Task(name, dueDate);
        this.tasksArr.push(newTask);
    }
}
//class for a group of projects 
class Projects {
    constructor() {
        this.listOfProjects = [new Project("Sample Project")];
    }
    addProjectToList(name) {
        let p = new Project(name);
        this.listOfProjects.push(p);
        return p
    }
    get allProjects() {
       return this.listOfProjects;
    }
    get numOfProjects() {
        return this.listOfProjects.length;
    }
}

let projects = new Projects();
let projArr = projects.allProjects;

projArr.forEach(renderProjects);
function renderProjects(project) {
    const newProjectDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const projectDom = document.getElementById("project-list");
    newProjectDiv.textContent = project.nameOfProject; 
    newProjectDiv.classList.add("project-item");
    projectDom.append(newProjectDiv);
    console.log(project.nameOfProject); 
}
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
addBtn.addEventListener("click", addProjectBtn);

function addProjectBtn() {
    let projName = prompt("name");
    projects.addProjectToList(projName);
    renderProjects(projects);
    console.log(projects.allProjects);
}
```

```html
<button id="add">add</button>

<div id="project-list" class="project-list"></div>
```

Comment: You should be using ```document.createElement("div")``` when creating a div not just calling ```newProjectDiv```.

Comment: You have not assigned any value to `newProjectDiv` inside `renderProjects` function. Change it to `let newProjectDiv = document.createElement('div');`. If that's not the problem then you should post a link to an online sandbox with your code (https://codesandbox.io for example). That will make it a lot easier to answer your question.

Comment: @Edward thank you, i've updated the code and it's creating a new <div> however, it's not rendering the name of the project that's being add; instead it displays [object, Object].

Comment: @RogerLopez Can you `console.log` the `project.name` that you are assigning to `.textContent`? It should be a string, and afaics, it is one in your code. Something else must be amiss.

Comment: @Bergi it logs undefined.

Comment: Then it wouldn't output "[object Object]", it would output "undefined". Can you provide a [mcve] please, ideally as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/1048572)?

Comment: @RogerLopez Thanks for the edit. So the problem is not the initial render, which displays "Sample Project" just fine, it's with the update you do when the add button was pressed. Hint: there's quite a difference between `projects.allProjects.forEach(renderProjects);` and `renderProjects(projects);`. (Try logging the whole `project` instead of only the `project.nameOfProject` in `renderProjects` to see)

Comment: @Bergi thank you! that's great info to keep a mental note on . i `renderProjects(new Project(projName))` and it's working perfect.

Comment: Actually I'd recommend to use the `Project` instance that is already returned by the `projects.addProjectToList(projName)` method call, instead of creating a second one. Also, consider renaming `renderProjects` to `renderProject`, since it renders only a single project.